# wp_register_sidebar_widget in loop within a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, widgets, sidebar, register-sidebar

I'm trying to dynamically create widgets based on a posts from a post type. The code is as below. This function is pulled from my plugin class:

```
public function initWidgets() {

        // Config Widgets
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );

        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) { 
            $wp_query->the_post();

            $widget_id = 'wp_as_'.get_the_ID();
            $widget_title = get_the_title();
            $widget_desc = get_the_title();
            var_dump($widget_id);
            wp_register_sidebar_widget(
                $widget_id,
                $widget_title,
                array($this, 'widgetDislay'),
                array('description' => $widget_desc)
            );
        }
    }

    public function widgetDislay($args) {
        // Widget display code
    }
```

This though only works once, even though its in the loop only one widget appears in the back end. Is there a reason for this? Or is there an alternative way of achieving what I'm trying here? I've seen people using `eval()` to dynamically add widgets, though I'd rather steer clear of this approach if at all possible.

Comment: This looks like a very messy way to do this. Why not create one widget with a dropdown that allows the user to select a post from your post type?

Comment: That actually sounds a much better way of doing it. Currently though when I drag the widget I created, it doesn't remain in the Available Widgets section. This will change though I imagine if I switch to using the WP_Widget class method?

Comment: Yes, you must, must, must use the Widget API.

Comment: I'll give that a go, thats for your help!

Comment: If you have trouble, [edit] this question with the modified code and alter the description and someone should be able to help  you.